how to install foremost or recoverjpeg?
I was trying to recover the pictures and some files in my corrupted sd card. All tutorials that I found is installing those two. When I tried installing it, it says unable to locate package recoverjpeg and it's the same with the foremost. Can someone help me or give me tutorial to install it. Alternative app will do. I just wanna recover the files. Thank youu

maybe https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-repair-and-clone-disk-with-ddrescue this will help

sudo apt install foremost works fine for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Maybe you'd like to specify what distribution you are running and how you were trying to install it.

See at: https://pkgs.org/download/foremost

i already tried doing sudo apt install thingy and it says that.. unable to locate it

got new problem.. i tried following the instruction of one user on a same problem as mine. It made it worst. My laptop neither my phone can detect the sd card

No "new problem" in comments, please. The format here is Question/Answer. Not conversation. Comments are how we ask you to improve or refine your Question. Then you edit your Question -- your Question is how you communicate to us. When your Question has enough information to be answerable, then somebody will write an Answer.

This question is similar to: How do I enable the "Universe" repository?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Both foremost and recoverjpeg are available in the universe repository in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.
